# How can I read all files from directory and put in an existing datagrindview

Tags: c#, file, datagridview, io

I have got this code.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
    int xy = dataGridView1.Rows.Count;
    string[] Files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"f:\ecet\");

    foreach (string sFile in Files)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            string fileCont = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(sFile);

            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = fileCont.ToString();       
        }
    }
}
```

I have got the fault. In the "ecet" folder i have got 3 files. (all .txt)

when i run the programm, this is put only the content of the last txt file all three rows of datagrindview.

I want put first txt to the first row, the secound to the secound row and soo on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this one:

```
// Declare an array, in which you will store the contents of your file.
string[] contents = new string[Files.Length];

// For each file in you Files collection read it's contents and add it to the contents array
 for(int i=0; i<contents.Length; i++)
     contents[i] = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Files[i]);

// Set the datasource of your data grid view and databind it.
dataGridView1.DataSource = contents;
dataGridView1.dataBind();
```

Comment: hello in this line "string[] contents = new string[Files.Count];" I got error.: Cannot convert method group 'Count' to non-delegate type 'int'. Did you intend to invoke the method?

Comment: @user3715465 I am sorry but I can;t get your comment.

Comment: hello in this line "string[] contents = new string[Files.Count];" I got error.: Cannot convert method group 'Count' to non-delegate type 'int'. Did you intend to invoke the method?

Comment: @user3715465 hey I have edited my post. So please tye the updated one. I don't use anymore the `Count`. I use the `Length` property of the array object.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
    string[] Files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"f:\ecet\");

    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    table.Columns.Add("Content".ToString());

    foreach (string sFile in Files)
    {
        string fileCont = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(sFile);
        DataRow dr = table.NewRow();
        dr["Content"] = fileCont;
        table.Rows.Add(dr);

    }

    dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
}
```

Try this :)

With your code you overwrite all Cells for every new file.

Answer (score 0):

here u can do it with Linq

```
var files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"f:\ecet\").Select(t => Sytem.IO.File.ReadAllText(t)).ToList();
dataGridView1.DataSource = files;
```